# Solve $y^2=x^4+x+2$ in $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have to solve $y^2=x^4+x+2$ in $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ and right now I am stuck. This is how far I came:

A little manipulation yields $y^2-2=x(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$. $x=1$ and $y=\pm 2$ are solutions. Assume from now on that $y$ is positive and $x>1$. I somehow want to find a prime $p=\pm 3\mod 8$ which  divides this expression so that $y^2=2\mod p$ and this is not possible then. But I really don't know how to do this. I really need some hints. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hint: $x^4+x+2$ is between $(x^2)^2$ and $(x^2+1)^2$ for $x>2$.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't get it. Is there a reason why you write it as $(x^2)^2$ and not just $x^4$?$

Comment: @Badshah: that is the point of the hint.  What can $y$ be?

Comment: @RossMillikan So what I understand from this is that $(x^2)^2$ is a square and $(x^2+1)^2$ is next square, but $y^2=x^4+x+2<(x^2+1)^2$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Exactly.  This proves that $x \le 2$, which doesn't leave many to check.  You do have to check $x=-2$, finding that $y=\pm 4, x=-2$ is a solution.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks:)